# "Delete" versus "vote to delete"?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

I was looking at [this off-topic posting](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/18298/could-you-make-a-calculator-without-electronics-using-only-wire-electricity).  Hovering over the "delete" link offered me the chance to "vote to delete".

Since I concurred with the consensus that it was essentially a duplicate of another question, I wanted to vote in favour.

"Click".

Instant deletion!

Did my vote happen to be the one that pushed the vote-count over the necessary limit, or is there some instant-delete privilege I am unaware of?   If the former, then what's the limit, please? If the latter, then the hover-prompt was misleading.

(I imagine there's some FAQ that says all this but I could not find it on a cursory search).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have insta-delete privileges; only [♦ moderators have that privilege](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators). (And authors can delete their post singlehandedly, but that's not the case here.)

> Did my vote happen to be the one that pushed the vote-count over the necessary limit

I think so; that limit is three (except for questions with a high score, which again is not the case here). But you *should* see the number of pending delete votes, and upon hover should show how many votes are deleted, like this:

[image]

There *should* be a banner above the question showing who voted to delete it. (I can't see it, I don't have enough reputation.)

Comment: I don't recall seeing any such 'N more votes' message, but maybe there was. Thanks.

Comment: @another-dave: Just to confirm and add to the answer.  Yes, yours was the third vote.